# NHibernate - Finding bad mappings

Tags: nhibernate

Are there any tools available, or perhaps utility methods within NHibernate, which may help me to nail down which mapping is throwing a "The given key is not present in the dictionary"?

I understand that I must have a bad mapping, but I have hundreds of domain objects. What can I do to locate the source of my error more quickly?

From the NHibernate 2.1.2GA Source:

```
private PersistentClass GetPersistentClass(string className)
{
    PersistentClass pc = configuration.classes[className]; // <- "The given key was not present in the dictionary"
    if (pc == null)
    {
     throw new MappingException("persistent class not known: " + className);
    }
    return pc;
}
```

And in this case, className is System.Int32.

Ok, so I had an int field marked `<many-to-one>` instead of `<property>`. I ended up digging up the source for NH and debugging to get to this point.

Comment: For me, this time, it's on Configuration.BuildSessionFactory(); no inner exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NHibernate Mapping: Creating Sanity Checks](http://ayende.com/blog/1595/nhibernate-mapping-creating-sanity-checks)

```
[Test]
public void AllNHibernateMappingAreOkay()
{
   IDictionary allClassMetadata = session.SessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata();
   foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in allClassMetadata)
   {
        session
            .CreateCriteria((Type) entry.Key)
            .SetMaxResults(0)
            .List();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is fine when your ISessionFactory has already been built, but what about before?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to test against a database without a proper Factory. :)

Comment: +1 for the concept, but in implementing I had to use var instead of IDictionary/DictionaryEntry and I had to use Type.GetType(entry.Key + ",My.Assembly") instead of (Type)entry.Key.  Also, it didn't uncover an error in my mapping that is causing the missing key message. :)